# Show that if two sets $A, B$ are NOT equal, then $(A\cup B)$ is NOT a subset of $ (A\cap B)).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning set theory and am stuck at this question:

Show that:

$$(A\neq B) \rightarrow \neg((A\cup B) \subseteq (A\cap B)).$$

Then deduce that:

$$((A\cup B) \subseteq (A\cap B)) \rightarrow (A=B).$$

Comment: Maybe drawing a Venn diagram would help

Comment: For the second one, recall that $(p\to q)\leftrightarrow(\lnot q\to\lnot p)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A \neq B$ then $A \nsubseteq B$ or $B \nsubseteq A$.
Suppose, without loss of generality, that $A \nsubseteq B$, and let $a \in A \setminus B$.
Then $a \in A \cup B$, but $a \notin A \cap B$.

Comment: Sorry but I dont really understand the explaination

Comment: To the OP: If there exists $a$ with $a\in C$ and $a\not \in D$ then $C$ can't be a subset of $D$.... So with $C=A\cup B$ and $D=A\cap B$:  If  $A\ne B$ , then there exists $a\in A\Delta B=((A $ \   $B)\cup (B$  \ $A)), $ and any such $a$ belongs to $C$ but not to $D.$

Comment: @BloopieBloops it is as user254665 wrote. More specifically, I picked $a \in A$ such that $a \notin B$. Then $a \notin A \cap B$ because $a \notin B$; but $a \in A \cup B$ because $a \in A$. If this is not enough, say which part you don't understand.

Comment: @amrsa hi, i tried to digest it, from your solution, because A≠B, then by the definition it is not in either A⊈B or B⊈A. Which means that a can be in either A or B (A∪B) but not in the intersection which means (A∪B)⊆(A∩B) is false and at the main question, it is surrounded by a negation which means RHS is true. and LHS (A≠B) is also true. So (A≠B)→¬((A∪B)⊆(A∩B)) is true as TRUE → TRUE = TRUE. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think you got it, even if you have an explanation that is a bit confusing. It's just that saying that $\neg(A \cup B \subseteq A \cap B)$ is, in my opinion more clear if we say, equivalently, that $A \cup B \nsubseteq A \cap B$, but apart from that it seems you understood it.

Comment: Glad that i got it right, I lost myself halfway while i was typing that. Also is it possible to solve this using the logic way? The one that includes demorgans law

Comment: It is possible to do it using de Morgan laws. Let $A'$ denote the complement of $A$ (what is not in $A$). Then $a \notin A$ or $a \notin B$ iff $a \in A' \cup B'$ which, by de Morgan is $a \in (A \cap B)'$ and this is iff $a \notin A \cap B$. But you still have to start by saying that if $A \neq B$ then there is $a \in A \setminus B$ or $a \in B \setminus A$.